# Proving upper bound complexity for a recursive function?

Tags: recursion, big-o, time-complexity

I am confused on how to use mathematical induction to prove Big O for a recursive function, given using its recursion relation.

**Example:**

> The recurrence relation for recursive implementation of Towers of Hanoi is T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1
>   and T(1) = 1. We claimed that this recursive method is O(n) = 2n - 1. Prove this claim using the mathematical induction.

In the case of recursion, do I always assume that n = k-1, rather than n=k? This is the assumption that the lecture notes give.

> Assume f(n-1) = 2^(n-1) - 1 is true.

I understand with non-recursive mathematical induction we assume that n = k, because it is only a change of variables. Why then, is it safe to assume that n = k - 1?

Comment: I would ask this as Stack Exchanges [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) site instead as it's more suited there.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.  Tag removed.

Comment: In mathematical induction, the "assumption" isn't something you really assume to be true. It is a statement of a *sufficient condition*. What you are hoping to show is that if the condition about one number is true, then it logically implies that some conclusion holds for the next number as well. Then, you show that the condition is true for a first number, and combined with what the condition implies, you prove the conclusion by cascading infinitely across the integers. That's how induction works. If some different choice of variables makes the math more convenient, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @jpw Actually, if you look at the description of the [tag:induction] tag, it says that pure math questions are flat out off topic for SO.

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't see any induction tag on the post though, and I do believe that the chances of getting a good answer to this would be better on [cs.se] or maybe [math.se], although the point is moot now, as it's already been answered.

Comment: @jpw I was agreeing with you. I was saying that this question is off topic, and thus your suggestion of going to http://cs.stackexchange.com could have legitimately been much more forceful. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way: Postulate a non-recursive formula for `T` and proove it. After that, show that the formula you found is in the Big O you wanted.

For the proof, you may use induction, which is quick and easy in that case. To do that, you first show that your formula holds for the first value (usually `0` or `1`, in your example that's `1` and trivial).

Then you show that if it holds for any number `n - 1`, it also holds for its successor `n`. For that you use the definition for `T(n)` (in your example that's `T(n) = 2 T(n - 1) + 1`): as you know that your formla holds for `n - 1`, you can replace occurences of `T(n - 1)` with your formula. In your example you then get (with formula `T(n) = 2^n - 1`)

```
T(n) = 2T(n - 1) + 1
     = 2(2^(n - 1) - 1) + 1
     = 2^n - 2 + 1
     = 2^n + 1
```

As you can see, it holds for `n` if we assume it holds for `n - 1`.

Now comes the trick of induction: we showed that our formula holds for `n = 1`, and we showed that if it holds for any `n = k - 1`, it holds for `k` as well. That is, as we prooved it for `1`, it is also proven for `2`. And as it is proven for `2`, it is also proven for `3`. And as it is...

Thus, we do not assume that the term is true for `n - 1` in our proof, we only made a statement under the assumption that it is true, then prooved our formula for one initial case, and used induction.

Comment: The first step in your math confused me. You might want to add an extra step to show you're distributing the 2 for thick heads like mine. =)